# Creating border around a column in Highcharts with different border widths for top and bottom

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a border around two parts of a stacked column in Highcharts.
Right now I can create the borders separately for each part but this way they will be separated by a line in the middle of them. (http://jsfiddle.net/chazyzyj/) Is there a way to set the top and bottom part of the border to different sizes?
Or any other solutions?

```
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1],
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'red',
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'red',
}]
```

Comment: "they will be separated by a line in the middle of them" -- What line are you reffering to? what am I looking for/at in the example?

Comment: What I was trying to say is that I want just one border surrounding the two sections of the column, not two separate borders. And in order to achieve the appearance of a single border, I'm trying to set the bottom part of the top border and top part of the bottom border to 0. Hope this is more clear!

Comment: At this moment you need to use the loop, iterate on each point and extract all point in the x. Then use [Renderer.path()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path) to add custom line, because the border cannot be customised like you have in mockup.

Comment: Just to add to Sebastian's comment - this is a limitation in SVG standard, it doesn't support different border styles on different sides of a rect. So you'd need to do this manually.